# Take a string and pass it to a delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I searched a lot but could not find an answer, I will be very grateful for your help!
I need to take a string and pass it to another location, but I cannot figure out how to do it in my case
[image]

```
func addTagLabels() {
    for tag in hashtags {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("#\(tag)", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        button.frame.size.width = button.intrinsicContentSize.width + tagPadding
        button.frame.size.height = tagHeight
        
        containerView.addSubview(button)
        tagLabels.append(button)
    }
}

@objc func didTap() {
    delegate?.didTap(tag: tag)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways.

**Way 1**

Assign array index to your button tag. And on did tap action get index and get data from the index.

Like this

```
func addTagLabels() {
    for (index, tag) in hashtags.enumerated() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.tag = index //<--- Here assign index
        
       // Other code
    }
}
```

Retrieve data

```
@objc func didTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let tagData = hashtags[sender.tag]
    delegate?.didTap(tag: tagData)
}
```

**Way 2**

Create a custom UIButton subclass and pass the value. Like this

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var data: String = ""
}

func addTagLabels() {
    for tag in hashtags {
        let button = CustomButton()
        button.setTitle("#\(tag)", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.data = tag //<-- Here
        // Other code
    }
}

@objc func didTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let btn = sender as? CustomButton {
        delegate?.didTap(tag: btn.data)
    }
}
```